# Passing on button click listeners via Bundle in AlertDialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I have a simple class:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final DialogInterface.OnClickListener DUMMY_ON_BUTTON_CLICKED_LISTENER = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do nothing
        }
    };

    public static final class Builder implements Parcelable {

        public static final Creator<Builder> CREATOR = new Creator<Builder>() {
            @Override
            public Builder createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new Builder(source);
            }

            @Override
            public Builder[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Builder[size];
            }
        };

        private Optional<Integer> title;
        private Optional<Integer> message;
        private Optional<Integer> positiveButtonText;
        private Optional<Integer> negativeButtonText;

        public Builder() {
            title = Optional.absent();
            message = Optional.absent();
            positiveButtonText = Optional.absent();
            negativeButtonText = Optional.absent();
        }

        public Builder(Parcel in) {
            title = (Optional<Integer>) in.readSerializable();
            message = (Optional<Integer>) in.readSerializable();
            positiveButtonText = (Optional<Integer>) in.readSerializable();
            negativeButtonText = (Optional<Integer>) in.readSerializable();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            out.writeSerializable(title);
            out.writeSerializable(message);
            out.writeSerializable(positiveButtonText);
            out.writeSerializable(negativeButtonText);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        public Builder withTitle(Integer title) {
            this.title = Optional.fromNullable(title);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withMessage(Integer message) {
            this.message = Optional.fromNullable(message);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPositiveButton(int buttonText) {
            this.positiveButtonText = Optional.fromNullable(buttonText);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withNegativeButton(int buttonText) {
            this.negativeButtonText = Optional.fromNullable(buttonText);
            return this;
        }

        private void set(AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder, final AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment) {
            if (title.isPresent()) {
                dialogBuilder.setTitle(title.get());
            }
            if (message.isPresent()) {
                dialogBuilder.setMessage(message.get());
            }
            if (positiveButtonText.isPresent()) {
                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText.get(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialogFragment.onPositiveButtonClickedListener.onClick(dialog, which);
                    }
                });
            }
            if (negativeButtonText.isPresent()) {
                dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(negativeButtonText.get(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialogFragment.onNegativeButtonClickedListener.onClick(dialog, which);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public AlertDialogFragment build() {
            return AlertDialogFragment.newInstance(this);
        }
    }


    private static final String KEY_BUILDER = "builder";

    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener onPositiveButtonClickedListener = DUMMY_ON_BUTTON_CLICKED_LISTENER;
    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener onNegativeButtonClickedListener = DUMMY_ON_BUTTON_CLICKED_LISTENER;


    private static AlertDialogFragment newInstance(Builder builder) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(KEY_BUILDER, builder);
        AlertDialogFragment fragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setOnPositiveButtonClickedListener(DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.onPositiveButtonClickedListener = listener != null ? listener : DUMMY_ON_BUTTON_CLICKED_LISTENER;
    }

    public void setOnNegativeButtonClickedListener(DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.onNegativeButtonClickedListener = listener != null ? listener : DUMMY_ON_BUTTON_CLICKED_LISTENER;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        Builder builder = getArguments().getParcelable(KEY_BUILDER);
        builder.set(alertDialogBuilder, this);
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }


}
```

Now I have to set *on button click listeners* in `SimpleDialogFragment` directly, because I can't pass the *listeners* via `Bundle` (args). But I want to - so it would look like instantiating an `AlertDialog`:

```
AlertDialogFragment dialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment.Builder()
                .withTitle(R.string.no_internet_connection)
                .withMessage(messageId)
                .withPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).build();
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_TAG_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
```

But now I should set listeners this way:

```
AlertDialogFragment dialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment.Builder()
                .withTitle(R.string.no_internet_connection)
                .withMessage(messageId)
                .withPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok)
                .build();
dialogFragment.setOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_TAG_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
```

Perhaps setting *on button click listeners* directly to `DialogFragment` instance, rather than passing them via `Bundle` arguments, is not safe, because the recommended way to pass arguments to `Fragment` is passing them via `Bundle` arguments.

Comment: Why do you want this moved to Stack Overflow?  I'm mainly asking because I cannot quite tell if what you're is off-topic here.

Comment: @Jamal Because probably I'll get an answer to my question there

Comment: But unless it's off-topic here first, it shouldn't be moved.  That's what I'm trying to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to grasp what you are trying to accomplish here. I just can't find a reason for why you are doing what you do. You are serializing title, message, positive button text and negative button text, ok, that I can understand. But serializing the listener, which really is *logic*? That's not an easy task.

There is really nothing wrong with setting listeners directly to the `AlertDialogFragment` instance.

For the record, you don't have to call `dialog.dismiss();` in your listener methods. In fact, with the way Android dialogs work, you can pass `null` as the listener and it will by default simply close the dialog.

Your `AlertDialogFragment.Builder` class seems to be primarily a wrapper around `AlertDialog.Builder` which doesn't really feel necessary to me. Are you really sure that you need this class?